# ReactiveSwift buffered pipe

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-swift

How can a [buffered replay subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) be implemented in [ReactiveSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift)?

I've looked at [`replayLazily(upTo:)`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/abcdc22fecdef777eaf4dda5cd4b410e24aceae7/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L2623) operator of `SignalProducer`, and also the `pipe()` function of the `Signal` type, however I can't see a straightforward way of creating something equivalent to Rx [`ReplaySubject`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#ReplaySubject).

This brings up the following questions as well:

1. ReactiveSwift implements `Subject` with `Signal.pipe()`, however you can't specify a buffer for the pipe the same way you can for a Rx [ReplaySubject](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#ReplaySubject). Are there any workarounds?
2. [`replayLazily(upTo:)`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/abcdc22fecdef777eaf4dda5cd4b410e24aceae7/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L2623) operator is missing from the [`Signal`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/Documentation/ReactivePrimitives.md#signal-a-unidirectional-stream-of-events) type. I guess this is not so bad since you can create a [`SignalProducer` from a `Signal`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/5c8fe420bec81f3d7aaddbe24a93be16d3d276e3/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L45). But why does `Signal` not have the same operator?

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Or am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Signal` docs](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/5c8fe420bec81f3d7aaddbe24a93be16d3d276e3/Sources/Signal.swift#L9) say:

> An observer of a Signal will see the exact same sequence of events as all other observers. In other words, events will be sent to all observers at the same time.

This is in contrast to producers, which create a new signal each time they are started, which means it's possible for each observer to see different events.

The buffering scenario requires each observer to receive a list of current values in the buffer upon subscription, and other observers should not receive these values each time a new observer is added. Therefore, each observer needs their own signal, and that means the buffering mechanism must be implemented as a *producer* which can create a new signal for each subscriber.

There's a [good discussion from 2016](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/2639) when `replayLazily` was added that hopefully clarifies the thinking behind the operator and why it absolutely can't be a part of `Signal`.

Comment: That discussion thread cleared things up for me quite a bit. Thank you very much.